# Disable WordPress auto paragraph

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to remove the wp auto p. I've tried both `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');` inside my theme's functions.php file and any plugin available to do this, but none of them are actually working.

Also i am not using any plugin that could be placing these p tags, so I am very confused.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, i am using `the_content()` in my template, and also adding `remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');` doesn't remove the auto paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

/* 
    Template Name: Text template.
*/

get_header(); ?>
<?php 
    if(have_posts()):
        while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
            <div class="color-1">
                <div class="content">
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div> 
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    endif;
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The paragraph around `<?php the_content(); ?>` was the reason why.